# Bat command to check if a directory has a file with a specific size

Tags: shell, batch-file

Is there a bat command which checks if a specific directory (not recursive in subdiretories) has a file with a specific size (like 109485 bytes)?

If I have to scan the entire directory only to check this, is it possible to only scan the 5 most recent files (last changed) to check if their size matches?

I cant scan an entire directory cause this code will execute every 3 second so I really need something really efficient.

Comment: Is powershell an option?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to involve PowerShell in the process, you could put something like this in a batch file.

```
PowerShell -Command "ls C:\Windows\System32\ | Where-Object {$_.length -eq 30720}"
```

This command lists all the files in system32 and then filters the list by files that are 30720 bytes.  Where-Object also has a bunch of other useful properties and switches that you can filter by.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee177028(v=technet.10)